# Number of AMPs consumed by a session in Teradata

Tags: session, teradata

I am new to teradata. I have a Stored Procedure which is taking lot of time on server. I just want to know How many AMPs it is using. I have the session id of the Process and only the procedure will be running in that session.So, with the session id available, can I query something on DBC tables and know how many AMPs are being used for that session.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Teradata?

Comment: Can you show the SP source?

Answer (score 1):

A Stored Procedure runs on a single Parsing Engine, only the actual SQL statements will run on AMPs, either on one, some or all AMPs.

But whenever someone complains about slow SPs on Teradata it's usually because there's some loop or cursor for processing data. A cursor is sequential (FETCH NEXT) and this is worst case on a parallel database system like Teradata. Rewriting it using SQL will run a few magnitudes faster.

Comment: Yes agreed. But I want to know whether the no of amps vary query by query in the sp and what is the whole count of the process

Comment: The number of AMPs always varies based on the SQL (no matter if it's submitted from within a SP or standalone), if it's a PI-access it's single AMP, USI -> 2 AMPs, NUSI/FTS -> all AMPs. The only way to see the actual plan is an Explain of the individual SQL statement submitted within the SP.

Answer (score 0):

In Teradata 14 and newer (possibly 13.10), you have access the System PMPC APIs via SQL that allow you to monitor active DBC/SQL sessions. If you have access to Viewpoint you can use that as well.

```
SELECT UserName
     , AmpCount
     , ReqCPU
     , ReqIO
     , ReqSpool
     , (1 - AvgAMPCPUSec) / HotAmp1CPU AS CPUSkew
  FROM TABLE(MonitorSession({HostIDIn},'{UserNameIn}', {SessionIDIn})) ;
```

> **HostIDIn**: -1 includes all hosts
>
> **UserNameIn**: '*' includes all users
>
> **SessionNoIn**: 0 (zero) includes all sessions

Comment: table means which table?? or is it simply table?

Comment: MonitorSession() returns a table object, hence the TABLE in the FROM clause.

Comment: monitorsession(-1,username,sessionid) is this right?

Comment: If you replace the username and session id with the actual values, yes. Or if it is part of a larger query it may also work but it would depend on your SQL.